# Why is "No one else in my team cares about optimization, what should I do?" off topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[No one else in my team cares about optimization, what should I do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83836/no-one-else-in-my-team-cares-about-optimization-what-should-i-do/83841?noredirect=1#comment240243_83841)

is closed as

> "Questions require a goal that we can address. Rather than explaining the difficulties of your situation, explain what you want to do to make it better. For more information, see this meta post." – gnat, IDrinkandIKnowThings, Christopher Estep, Masked Man, Richard U

The question includes

> I've asked if we could at least compress the images and minify the CSS/JS but the rest of the team aren't worried about it. I'm happy to do this work myself and it goes against my principles to produce a website that's slow. But I need their approval to make these changes. I don't have the authority to force this issue since I'm a contractor.

which explains what OP wants to do to make the situation better.

The meta post includes

> Our goal here at The Workplace is to help out people in the future who are facing the same problem.

Question looks fine to me.

Bluntly -- what the heck?

Comment: Find out why they don't appear to care. Proceed from there. But part of being a contractor is accepting that your job is to do what is assigned to you, not what you'd do if you were running the project. The customer is not always right, but the customer is the one with the money, and you need to decide whether you care more about being right of being paid.

Comment: @keshlam that's an answer to the *original* question (which basically appears in multiple of the answers), not this meta question.

Answer (score 2):

The OP's "difficulty" is that the client is not interested in his proposed improvements, but that goes against his principles. The part you have quoted refers to improving page load times, which is a *different* problem. His proposed solution does not address the actual difficulty, and hence, doesn't make the situation better.

OP's question here is not "how do I improve page load times?", and anyway, the OP already knows a solution to that.

**Update** OP has edited the question, I have cast the final reopen vote, and the question is reopened now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52690/discussion-between-masked-man-and-djechlin).